# How can i catch an event when delete my app from background

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I catch an event when delete app from background?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear whether you mean actually remove the app from the device or just kill the running process. But either way the answer is the same:

You can't.

If there's any state that you want to record, you need to do it as the app goes into the background and *not* when the app is killed.

The documentation says that `applicationWillTerminate:` *may* be called. I have never seen that happen.

Comment: My problem is regarding to local notification. I want to stop notification when app's removed from background. That reason why i want to catch this event for showing a appropriate pop-up.

Comment: As I noted in your other (very similar) question, that's probably not something you should be doing. That's most likely why Apple don't let you do it.

Comment: I saw one app do this. This is [Downcast](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/downcast/id393858566?mt=8). While downloading you minimize it and then kill. Then have a pop-up showed up.